# JAVA - Priority Queue Compare Double Descending Order

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I have a working class that can order in ascending order but if I switch the logic around my results are not what I'm expecting. Maybe I don't understand how the Comparator works. If I use poll to print out my queue then I lose that data. How could I print it out without losing the data? Currently i make a temp queue and reinsert into the old queue.

```
public class Example
{
    private static Logger log   = LogClass.getLog();

    private PriorityQueue<Double> integerPriorityQueue;

    void inputIntoQueue(Collection<Double> queueNumbers)
    {
        Comparator<Double> comparator = new DoubleComparator();
          integerPriorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Double>(comparator);
          integerPriorityQueue.addAll(queueNumbers);

          Iterator<Double> it = integerPriorityQueue.iterator();

         log.trace("Priority queue values are: ");

          while (it.hasNext())
              {
                log.trace( it.next()); 
              }      
    }   
}

 class DoubleComparator implements Comparator<Double>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Double arg0, Double arg1)
        {
                if (arg1 < arg0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                if ( arg1  > arg0 )
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Update to my code

```
public class Example
{
    private static Logger              log                 = LogClass.getLog();
    private DoubleComparatorDescending  comparator         = new DoubleComparatorDescending();
    private PriorityQueue<Double>      doublePriorityQueue  = new PriorityQueue<Double>(
                                                                   comparator);
    private PriorityQueue<Double>      tempQueue           = new PriorityQueue<Double>(
                                                                   comparator);

    public PriorityQueue<Double> getDoublePriorityQueue()
        {
            return doublePriorityQueue;
        }


    void inputIntoQueue(Collection<Double> queueNumbers)
        {
            doublePriorityQueue.addAll(queueNumbers);
            printQueue(doublePriorityQueue);
        }

    private void printQueue(PriorityQueue<Double> integerPriorityQueue2)
        {
            log.trace("Priority queue values are: ");

            while (doublePriorityQueue.size() > 0)
                {
                    Double tempDouble = doublePriorityQueue.poll();
                    log.trace(tempDouble);
                    tempQueue.add(tempDouble);
                }
            doublePriorityQueue = tempQueue;
        }
}

class DoubleComparatorDescending implements Comparator<Double>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Double arg0, Double arg1)
        {
            if (arg1 < arg0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            if (arg1 > arg0)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            return 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The elements returned by a PriorityQueue's iterator are not ordered using the queue's order.

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) says:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

The only guarantee is that the **head** of the queue, returned by `peek()` or `poll()`, is the smallest of all the elements in the queue.

If you want a sorted collection, use a TreeSet or a List that you sort.

Comment: How do print each value without emptying out the Queue?

Comment: Just as you did. Simply don't expect the elements to be in any particular order. If you want to display them in a given order, then transform the queue to an array, sort the array, and print the elements of the sorted array.

Comment: Yes but if I use poll which will get the data in order but it also takes out the date from the queue.  I make a temp queue and copy that back to the old queue after it prints out? Is this best way of printing the data out in order?

Answer (score 0):

Also, as per the **javadoc**, The Iterator provided in method PriorityQueue.iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

Hence,The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

Comment: How do print each value without emptying out the Queue?